# Error while trying to save on .txt during a CUDA mexfunction in MatLab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, cuda

I have 2 mexfucntions (1 C++ and 1 CUDA) which do the same calculation and I am compairing them.

Now I am working on the CUDA mexfucntion and I need to print on a .txt certain values in order to perform a debug. I used the same process in the C++ mexfunction and it worked properly. Now in the CUDA code it doesn't work and it even makes MatLab crash.

In the main I use the following simple code:

```
std::ofstream test;
test.open("test.txt");
test << "test"; 
test << "\n";
test.close();
```

The code is NOT placed inside a CUDA kernel, because I already know the I cannot call ad host fucntion from a global function. The code is place in the main which runs on CPU. The sintax must be the same as C++ mexfunction and in fact it is.. but on C++ works and here it doesn't.

The file "test.txt" is created but nothing is written on it... so the error is here and I am sure about that because I tried to comment every command and the one which always makes matlab crash is this one:

test.open("test.txt");

[MatLab error is always the same, an access violation, as you can see in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wRr9.jpg)

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: if it's not a cuda function then it's not a cuda question, imo

Comment: well the abovementioned piece of code is located inside a CUDA mexfunction so i think it is! also because the SAME code in C++ mexfunction works just fine.. so the problem MUST be CUDA-related

Comment: Probably you where referring to my sentence "The code is NOT placed inside a CUDA kernel"... well... read all the post!! It is not inside a kernel because you CANNOT call an host function from a CUDA kernel... but it is still inside a CUDA mexfunction..

Comment: @Jonas CUDA does not modify the behavior of `std::ofstream` thus there should be something else wrong, not related to CUDA. Please post a MCVE that reproduces this error.

Comment: @AnderBiguri the problem is that i cannot make easily an MCVE.. i have 2 VS2010 big projects with many libraries and include paths.. the first generates the C++ mexfunction and the second the CUDA mexfunction.. they execute the same commands (with all the necessary "translations" from one language to the other) with the SAVINGS written the same in C++ language in both the mexfunction because, as you said, the std::ofstream behaviour is the same. That being said.. when I run the CUDA mex, matlab crashes exactly at the moment of writing on the txt..

Comment: I edited the post adding a screenshot of the crash report

Comment: @Jonas The thing about being able to make a MCVE is that it will help you find the problem. Really, I am running CUDA code with MATLAB, and your code doesnt throw any error.

Comment: I have 5 different files which works all together, plus 3 library and different folders of includes. It's simply not possibile to upload all that stuff here....

Comment: can be related: http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45307-clear-mex-causes-segmentation-fault-when-using-cuda-rt-api

Comment: no sadly it is not...

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys we realized that there is a compatibility problem when creating a CUDA project (my CUDA version in 7.5) with VS2010.

You simply cannot generate a .txt file from a CUDA mexfunction using standard C++ iostream. You MUST use C syntax, namely:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("test.txt", "w");
char str[] = "This is a test";
fwrite(str , 1 , sizeof(str) , fp );
fclose(fp);
```

A good hint was taken here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/155378